# Why async/await with += operator not accumulating the value correctly?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've stumbled upon this question.

My instinct tells me the `sum` should be `3`. Could someone explain what is actually happening?

```js
let sum = 0;

async function add(num) {
    sum += await num;
}

add(1);
add(2);

setTimeout(() => console.log(sum), 100);
```

Comment: `sum += await sum` <=> `sum = sum + await sum`. Finding the duplicate…

Comment: Run them in series, e.g. `add(1).then(() => add(2))`.

Comment: You are not awaiting... check demo here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-eypsnk?file=index.js

Comment: (I wouldn’t run them in series. Avoid the trap with `let foo = await num; sum += foo;`.)

Comment: @Joel: Not a problem in JavaScript.

Comment: You could put `console.log(num,sum);` before and after the `sum+=` line.